# Centering section with label and title on separate lines

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, titlesec

I am trying to center a section title with the section label on one line, and the section name on the next. ie:

```
         |
     Article II
  This is the Title
         |
```

My attempt:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{Article \Roman{section}}}
\titleformat{name=\section}{\large\bfseries}{\center{\thesection}}{.5em}{\newline \centering}[]

\section{This is the Title}
```

I haven't found success with `centerline{}`, `centering` or `center{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\renewcommand{\thesection}{Article \Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
{\centering\Large\bfseries}%
{\rule{2pt}{12pt}\\\thesection\\#1\\\rule{2pt}{12pt}} % format
{0cm} % sep
{}

\begin{document}    
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{This should be centered}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [block] was the trick. Thanks for the answer